# Writing dictionary values as separate columns in csv using python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
list_of_dict = [
    {'text': '"Some text1"', 
     'topics': ['Availability', 'Waits'], 
     'categories': ['Scheduler']},
    {'text': 'Alot to improve'},
    {'text': 'More text '}
    ]
```

I am writing it to a csv file as follows:

```
with open("text.csv", 'wb') as resultFile:
            wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
            wr.writerow(['text', 'topics', 'categories'])

for d in list_of_dict:
    with open("text.csv", 'a') as f:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, d.keys())
            w.writerow(d)
```

This writes to the csv file as follows:

```
text            |  topics                   | categories
Some text1      | ['Availability', 'Waits'] | ['Scheduler']
Alot to improve |
More text       |
```

However, I want it that for each category and for each topic there should be a separate column, then if some topic exists from the `topics` list or some category exists from the `categories` list, then write `True` in that cell for that particular topic/category of the text else write `False`.

OUTPUT:

```
text             | Availability | Waits | Scheduler |
Some text1       | True         | True  | True      |
Alot to improve  | False        | False | False     |
More text        | False        | False | False     |
```

How can this be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For each `row` it will probably be easiest to start with a default dictionary containing all required column values set to `False`, then as each row in your `list_of_dict` is read in, you can spot if it contains the requred keys, and update your `row` accordingly:

```
import csv

list_of_dict = [
    {'text': '"Some text1"', 'topics': ['Availability', 'Waits'], 'categories': ['Scheduler']},
    {'text': 'Alot to improve'},
    {'text': 'More text '}]

all_topics = ["Availability", "Waits"]
all_categories = ["Scheduler"]
fieldnames = ["text"] + all_topics + all_categories

with open("text.csv", 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=fieldnames, dialect='excel')
    csv_output.writeheader()

    for d in list_of_dict:
        # Build a default row
        row = {v:False for v in all_topics + all_categories}
        row['text'] = d['text'].strip('"')

        if 'topics' in d:
            row.update({topic:True for topic in d['topics']})
        if 'categories' in d:
            row.update({category:True for category in d['categories']})

        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Giving you a `text.csv` file:

```
text,Availability,Waits,Scheduler
Some text1,True,True,True
Alot to improve,False,False,False
More text ,False,False,False
```